# SQL get latest availability per member

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have a situation where I store in a table each member's availability.
It's a simple table with 4 column.

```
CREATE TABLE availablities (
  availablity_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  member_id serial,
  availablity_status_id serial,
  start_date timestamp
);
```

Each member can have multiple records in the table and to get the current status
I get for each member the record that has the most recent start_date that is smaller then now().

I first tried with a naive Max() and Group by query

```
select 
  status_code, max(start_date) start_date,availablities.member_id 
from 
  availablities
join 
  availablity_status on availablity_status.availablity_status_id = availablities.availablity_status_id
where 
  start_date <= now() 
group by 
  status_code,availablities.member_id;
```

But this return multiple records per user as I get the most recent record by user and by status.

I finally came up with a query that gives me the expected result.

```
 select status_code,start_date,a2.member_id  from availablities a2 
 join availablity_status on availablity_status.availablity_status_id = a2.availablity_status_id
 where a2.availablity_id in(
     select 
        max(availablity_id)
     from availablities a 
     where 
        a.member_id = a2.member_id and 
        start_date in(
            select 
                max(start_date) start_date
            from availablities
            where 
            start_date <= now() 
            and a.member_id = availablities.member_id    
     )
);
```

But this query takes 60 times longer to execute and doesn't feel right.
I'm pretty sure there must be a better solution but I can't get my hands on it.

What is the correct way to get the expected result?

I've created a DB-fiddle to make it easier to see. Query 1 is incorrect and Query 2 is much slower when we have a couple more data.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWgvuj8kcms9F5CKuoKsny/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use a simple `row_number` window function here:

```
with a as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by member_id order by start_date desc, availablity_id desc) rn
    from availablities 
    where start_date<now()
)
select s.status_code, a.start_date, a.member_id
from a join availablity_status s on s.availablity_status_id=a.availablity_status_id
where rn=1
```

Note your data is not selective enough, so for member_id 3, is it available or not? What is the most recent date when there are two identical dates?

I added a tie-breaker to also sort by `availability_id` to get your expected results

Actually it's `availablity_id` - you seem to have a common typo here!

See your [updated Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWgvuj8kcms9F5CKuoKsny/2)

Comment: Thanks, Row_Number and partition by are exactly what I was looking for. It's even faster than my originally wrong request.